# Angularjs - how to force loading new code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my angularjs app I use gulp revving for auto change version of all js and all css file. But every time after I pull a new version of my code to production, my client on loading web page get some new and some old data.
In network console, a new version of script and css are loaded properly, but some data in view are old data. For new data, we need to make browser hard reset.

Is there any way to force the browser to load all new data??? Thnx

Comment: What you think about setTimeIntervel()?

Comment: Can you show me example? Where to set time interval? On index.html? Because all script and css have new version number... :/

Answer (score 1):

The best way is putting a query string in your script and css tag, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css-min/style.min.css?v=3" media="all">

<script src="/someScript.js?v=4"></script>
```

But in every version change you'll need update the "v" value.

Comment: Or let a build tool like webpack create script files with a hashed name so that the client sees always a new filename everytime the script has changed. If you do not use webpack, using timestamps instead of incremental version numbers would be an option, too.

Comment: @david I already use this, but with gulp revving... Every time when I start gulp task for revving, I get new version number like this script-aa46498.js and on next revving, dynamically gulp change version script-f79g55.js . But on this way I still get old data on first load after adding new code to production. Stephan Köninger I will try with timestamp